# Cross-Correlation Derivative

Tags: matrix-calculus, machine-learning

Given an input matrix,

$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{00} & x_{01} & x_{02} & x_{03} \\
    x_{10} & x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} \\
    x_{20} & x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} \\
    x_{30} & x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

a kernel

$$
W = \begin{bmatrix}
    w_{00} & w_{01} \\
    w_{10} & w_{11} 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and the result of cross-correlation

$$
\begin{align}
Z &= X \star W \\\\
Z &= \begin{bmatrix}
    z_{00} & z_{01} & z_{02} \\
    z_{10} & z_{11} & z_{12} \\
    z_{20} & z_{21} & z_{22}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
    z_{00} &= x_{00} w_{00} + x_{01} w_{01} + x_{10} w_{10} + x_{11} w_{11} \\
    z_{01} &= x_{01} w_{00} + x_{02} w_{01} + x_{11} w_{10} + x_{12} w_{11} \\
    z_{02} &= x_{02} w_{00} + x_{03} w_{01} + x_{12} w_{10} + x_{13} w_{11} \\  
    z_{10} &= x_{10} w_{00} + x_{11} w_{01} + x_{20} w_{10} + x_{21} w_{11} \\
    z_{11} &= x_{11} w_{00} + x_{12} w_{01} + x_{21} w_{10} + x_{22} w_{11} \\
    z_{12} &= x_{12} w_{00} + x_{13} w_{01} + x_{22} w_{10} + x_{23} w_{11} \\  
    z_{20} &= x_{20} w_{00} + x_{21} w_{01} + x_{30} w_{10} + x_{31} w_{11} \\
    z_{21} &= x_{21} w_{00} + x_{22} w_{01} + x_{31} w_{10} + x_{32} w_{11} \\
    z_{22} &= x_{22} w_{00} + x_{23} w_{01} + x_{32} w_{10} + x_{33} w_{11}
\end{align}
$$

I need to get the derivative of a loss function $l : \mathbb{R}^{c} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with respect to the kernel $W$.

I already have $\frac{\partial l}{\partial Z}$ and $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial W_{ij}}$,

$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial Z} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial l}{\partial z_{00}} & \frac{\partial l}{\partial z_{01}} & \frac{\partial l}{\partial z_{02}} \\
    \frac{\partial l}{\partial z_{10}} & \frac{\partial l}{\partial z_{11}} & \frac{\partial l}{\partial z_{12}} \\
    \frac{\partial l}{\partial z_{20}} & \frac{\partial l}{\partial z_{21}} & \frac{\partial l}{\partial z_{22}}
    \end{bmatrix} 
$$

$$
\newcommand{\grad}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\begin{array}{cc}
    \grad{Z}{w_{00}} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \grad{z_{00}}{w_{00}} & \grad{z_{01}}{w_{00}} & \grad{z_{02}}{w_{00}} \\
            \grad{z_{10}}{w_{00}} & \grad{z_{11}}{w_{00}} & \grad{z_{12}}{w_{00}} \\
            \grad{z_{20}}{w_{00}} & \grad{z_{21}}{w_{00}} & \grad{z_{22}}{w_{00}}
        \end{bmatrix} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x_{00} & x_{01} & x_{02} \\
            x_{10} & x_{11} & x_{12} \\
            x_{20} & x_{21} & x_{22}
        \end{bmatrix} &
    \grad{Z}{w_{01}} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \grad{z_{00}}{w_{01}} & \grad{z_{01}}{w_{01}} & \grad{z_{02}}{w_{01}} \\
            \grad{z_{10}}{w_{01}} & \grad{z_{11}}{w_{01}} & \grad{z_{12}}{w_{01}} \\
            \grad{z_{20}}{w_{01}} & \grad{z_{21}}{w_{01}} & \grad{z_{22}}{w_{01}}
        \end{bmatrix} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x_{01} & x_{02} & x_{03} \\
            x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} \\
            x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23}
        \end{bmatrix} \\
    \grad{Z}{w_{10}} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \grad{z_{00}}{w_{10}} & \grad{z_{01}}{w_{10}} & \grad{z_{02}}{w_{10}} \\
            \grad{z_{10}}{w_{10}} & \grad{z_{11}}{w_{10}} & \grad{z_{12}}{w_{10}} \\
            \grad{z_{20}}{w_{10}} & \grad{z_{21}}{w_{10}} & \grad{z_{22}}{w_{10}}
        \end{bmatrix} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x_{10} & x_{11} & x_{12} \\
            x_{20} & x_{21} & x_{22} \\
            x_{30} & x_{31} & x_{32}
        \end{bmatrix} &
    \grad{Z}{w_{11}} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \grad{z_{00}}{w_{11}} & \grad{z_{01}}{w_{11}} & \grad{z_{02}}{w_{11}} \\
            \grad{z_{10}}{w_{11}} & \grad{z_{11}}{w_{11}} & \grad{z_{12}}{w_{11}} \\
            \grad{z_{20}}{w_{11}} & \grad{z_{21}}{w_{11}} & \grad{z_{22}}{w_{11}}
        \end{bmatrix} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} \\
            x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} \\
            x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
$$

but I have no idea what to do next to get $\frac{\partial l}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial l}{\partial Z} \frac{\partial Z}{\partial W}$.

Comment: It may help to use [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) viz.$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial W_{ij}}=\frac{\partial l}{\partial Z_k}\frac{\partial Z_k}{\partial W_{ij}}.$$But I'm confused by your notation. You wrote $l:\,\Bbb R^c\mapsto\Bbb R$, suggesting $Z$ is  a vector, but then you write $z_{00}$, suggesting $SZ$ is a matrix for which the above should change $Z_k$ to $Z_{kl}$.

Comment: @J.G. $l$ isn't a function of $Z$, there are more steps, it's just I have $\frac{\partial l}{\partial Z}$, it could be $\frac{\partial l}{\partial Z} = \frac{\partial l}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial Z}$.

Comment: If $Z$ is not a vector, then in lieu of JG's formula, use the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\grad{\ell}{W_{ij}} &= \trace{\gradLR{\ell}{Z}^T\gradLR{Z}{W_{ij}}} \\
}$$ These scalar values are the components of the $\grad{\ell}{W}$ matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for J.G.'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788817/cross-correlation-derivative#comment10181128_4788817), I was able to derive a solution, even though I don't know if I'm using a correct notation, but the math checks out.

We can use Einstein notation to express cross-correlation

$$
\newcommand{\grad}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
Z_{[i,j]} = X_{[i+u,j+v]} W_{[u,v]}
$$

and the derivative in index notation

$$
\begin{align}
\grad{l}{W_{[s,t]}} 
&= \grad{l}{Z_{[i,j]}} \grad{Z_{[i,j]}}{W_{[s,t]}} \\
&= \grad{l}{Z_{[i,j]}} X_{[i+u,j+v]} \grad{W_{[u,v]}}{W_{[s,t]}} \\
&= \grad{l}{Z_{[i,j]}} X_{[i+u,j+v]} \delta_{[u,s]} \delta_{[v,t]} \\
&= \grad{l}{Z_{[i,j]}} X_{[i+s,j+t]} \\
&= X_{[s+i,t+j]} \grad{l}{Z_{[i,j]}}
\end{align}
$$

back to symbolic notation

$$
\grad{l}{W} = X \star \grad{l}{Z}
$$

Now if anyone would need $\grad{l}{X}$, here's a derivation

$$
\begin{align}
    \grad{l}{X_{[s,t]}} &= \grad{l}{Z_{[i,j]}} \grad{Z_{[i,j]}}{X_{[s,t]}} \\
                        &= \grad{l}{Z_{[i,j]}} \grad{ X_{[i+u,j+v]}}{X_{[s,t]}} W_{[u,v]} \\
                        &= \grad{l}{Z_{[i,j]}} \delta_{[i+u,s]} \delta_{[j+v,t]} W_{[u,v]}
\end{align}
$$

$\delta_{[i+u,s]}$ is only 1 when $_{s = i + u}$ or $_{u = s - i}$ and $\delta_{[j+v,t]}$ when $_{t = j + v}$ or $_{v = t - j}$, so

$$
\begin{align}
    &= \grad{l}{Z_{[i,j]}} \delta_{[u,s-i]} \delta_{[v,t-j]} W_{[u,v]} \\
                        &= \grad{l}{Z_{[i,j]}} W_{[s-i,t-j]} \\
    \grad{l}{X} &= \grad{l}{Z} \underset{\text{full}}{*} W
\end{align}
$$

where $\underset{\text{full}}{*}$ is full convolution.

Comment: $\tt+1\:$ Very nice question and answer